# Does 'sync=true' works when using ehcache in springboot2.0

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache

I am using `@cacheable` in `springboot2.0` with `EHcache`, but I am not sure if `sync=true` is supported?

How to check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Cacheable` allows you to specify the `sync` attribute to **ensure only a single thread is building the cache value**.

**How to check:**

Access the cached data by sending the two parallel request and modify the data. The second thread should get only updated value.